# Kafka Avro Producer (kafka-avro-console-producer) schema error when sending to kafka connect

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform, confluent-schema-registry

I am trying to use kafka-avro-console-producer to publish a message that has a key (with schema) and a value (with schema).  The kafka environment (confluent 6.2.0 versions for kafka, connect, zookeeper, schema registry) all start properly and I can confirm that my connector is installed. The problem is that when I send the message my Sink connector fails with an error that I am unable to diagnose.

Any help is appreciated:

I produce an AVRO message as follows:

```
docker exec -it schema-registry \
  /usr/bin/kafka-avro-console-producer \
  --broker-list http://kafka:9092 \
  --topic source-1 \
  --property value.schema='{"type":"record","name":"somerecord","fields":[{"name":"timestamp","type":"string"}, {"name":"data","type":"string"}]}' \
  --property parse.key=true \
  --property key.schema='{"type":"int"}' \
  --property key.separator=" "

1 {"timestamp":"some-timestamp", "data":"somedata"}
```

And receive the following error in the connect logs:

```
connect            | [2021-10-04 18:22:51,792] ERROR WorkerSinkTask{id=brodagroupsoftware-http-sink-connector-0} Error converting message key in topic 'source-1' partition 0 at offset 0 and timestamp 1633371770674: Converting byte[] to Kafka Connect data failed due to serialization error of topic source-1:  (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask)
connect            | org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.DataException: Converting byte[] to Kafka Connect data failed due to serialization error of topic source-1:
connect            |    at io.confluent.connect.json.JsonSchemaConverter.toConnectData(JsonSchemaConverter.java:118)
connect            |    at org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.Converter.toConnectData(Converter.java:87)
connect            |    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.convertKey(WorkerSinkTask.java:530)
connect            |    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.lambda$convertAndTransformRecord$1(WorkerSinkTask.java:493)
connect            |    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execAndRetry(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:156)
connect            |    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execAndHandleError(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:190)
connect            |    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execute(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:132)
connect            |    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.convertAndTransformRecord(WorkerSinkTask.java:493)
connect            |    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.convertMessages(WorkerSinkTask.java:473)
connect            |    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.poll(WorkerSinkTask.java:328)
connect            |    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.iteration(WorkerSinkTask.java:232)
connect            |    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.execute(WorkerSinkTask.java:201)
connect            |    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:182)
connect            |    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:231)
connect            |    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
connect            |    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
connect            |    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
connect            |    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
connect            |    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
connect            | Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Error deserializing JSON message for id 1
connect            | Caused by: java.io.IOException: Invalid schema "long" with refs [] of type AVRO
connect            |    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.CachedSchemaRegistryClient.lambda$getSchemaByIdFromRegistry$6(CachedSchemaRegistryClient.java:229)
connect            |    at java.base/java.util.Optional.orElseThrow(Optional.java:408)
connect            |    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.CachedSchemaRegistryClient.getSchemaByIdFromRegistry(CachedSchemaRegistryClient.java:227)
connect            |    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.CachedSchemaRegistryClient.getSchemaBySubjectAndId(CachedSchemaRegistryClient.java:298)
connect            |    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.CachedSchemaRegistryClient.getSchemaById(CachedSchemaRegistryClient.java:283)
connect            |    at io.confluent.kafka.serializers.json.AbstractKafkaJsonSchemaDeserializer.deserialize(AbstractKafkaJsonSchemaDeserializer.java:107)
connect            |    at io.confluent.kafka.serializers.json.AbstractKafkaJsonSchemaDeserializer.deserializeWithSchemaAndVersion(AbstractKafkaJsonSchemaDeserializer.java:208)
connect            |    at io.confluent.connect.json.JsonSchemaConverter$Deserializer.deserialize(JsonSchemaConverter.java:163)
connect            |    at io.confluent.connect.json.JsonSchemaConverter.toConnectData(JsonSchemaConverter.java:107)
connect            |    at org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.Converter.toConnectData(Converter.java:87)
connect            |    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.convertKey(WorkerSinkTask.java:530)
connect            |    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.lambda$convertAndTransformRecord$1(WorkerSinkTask.java:493)
connect            |    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execAndRetry(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:156)
connect            |    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execAndHandleError(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:190)
connect            |    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execute(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:132)
connect            |    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.convertAndTransformRecord(WorkerSinkTask.java:493)
connect            |    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.convertMessages(WorkerSinkTask.java:473)
connect            |    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.poll(WorkerSinkTask.java:328)
connect            |    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.iteration(WorkerSinkTask.java:232)
connect            |    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.execute(WorkerSinkTask.java:201)
connect            |    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:182)
connect            |    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:231)
connect            |    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
connect            |    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
connect            |    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
connect            |    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
connect            |    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
connect            | [2021-10-04 18:22:51,796] INFO HttpSinkTask:flush (com.brodagroup.datamesh.connect.httpsinkconnector.HttpSinkTask)
```

My docker-compose to start "connect" is shown below:

```
     connect:
        image: confluentinc/cp-kafka-connect:6.2.0
        hostname: connect
        container_name: connect
        depends_on:
          - zookeeper
          - kafka
        ports:
          - 8083:8083
        environment:
          CONNECT_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: "kafka:9092"
          CONNECT_REST_PORT: 8083
          CONNECT_REST_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME: "connect"
          CONNECT_GROUP_ID: compose-connect-group
          CONNECT_CONFIG_STORAGE_TOPIC: connect-configs
          CONNECT_OFFSET_STORAGE_TOPIC: connect-offsets
          CONNECT_STATUS_STORAGE_TOPIC: connect-status

          CONNECT_KEY_CONVERTER_SCHEMAS_ENABLE: "true"
          CONNECT_VALUE_CONVERTER_SCHEMAS_ENABLE: "true"
          CONNECT_KEY_CONVERTER: "io.confluent.connect.json.JsonSchemaConverter"
          CONNECT_KEY_CONVERTER_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL: "http://schema-registry:8081"
          CONNECT_VALUE_CONVERTER: "io.confluent.connect.json.JsonSchemaConverter"
          CONNECT_VALUE_CONVERTER_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL: "http://schema-registry:8081"

          CONNECT_LOG4J_ROOT_LOGLEVEL: "INFO"
          CONNECT_LOG4J_LOGGERS: "org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest=WARN,org.reflections=ERROR"
          CONNECT_CONFIG_STORAGE_REPLICATION_FACTOR: "1"
          CONNECT_OFFSET_STORAGE_REPLICATION_FACTOR: "1"
          CONNECT_STATUS_STORAGE_REPLICATION_FACTOR: "1"
          CONNECT_PLUGIN_PATH: '/usr/share/java'
```

Comment: You should add your HTTPSink connector config to the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the stacktrace, you are using `JsonSchemaConverter`, however, you  have produced Avro data.

Therefore, you should be using AvroConverter in your connector configs

Comment: OK.  Got it.  It looks like I am using the wrong console producer... What console producer would I use to send a JSON schema?

Comment: `kafka-console-producer` , but Avro will work fine for your use-case. https://www.confluent.io/blog/kafka-connect-deep-dive-converters-serialization-explained/

Comment: One quick question... I am looking at the kafka-console-producer and it is unclear how I can use a key schema as well as a value schema... I am probably missing something simple but this escapes me... any pointers are appreciated!

Comment: Oh, and I can see that I have a setup where the schema is registered automatically... how is this accomplished with the kafka-console-producer?

Comment: `kafka-console-producer` doesn't interact with any schema data.